# Unable to use current_user.id in faye extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, faye

I am using devise and faye. and I want to track all online users. so i thought of including a faye extension. in faye/faye_current_user.rb .  when i am using current_user.id in faye_current_user.rb it is throwing undefined variable error.

If you have anyother easy way to fetch online users please help me out.

Comment: You're gonna need to share the code for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the "current_user" method from devise isn't being called before your method inside of faye_current_user.rb.

A working solution is dependent upon the where this file is located and how your set current_user before calling the methods within that file.